# JQuery ajax POST request is a success but I still get my custom error message on my webpage

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After the JQuery POST request It's always displays my custom error message on the webpage when it's successfully registers the user in the database.

```php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

        <title>Rest API Authentication Example</title>
 <!-- Bootstrap 4 CSS and custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css" />

    </head>
<body>

<!-- navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" id='home'>Home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" id='update_account'>Account</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" id='logout'>Logout</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" id='login'>Login</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" id='sign_up'>Sign Up</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- /navbar -->

<!-- container -->
<main role="main" class="container starter-template">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">

            <!-- where prompt / messages will appear -->
            <div id="response"></div>

            <!-- where main content will appear -->
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>
<!-- /container -->

<!-- jQuery & Bootstrap 4 JavaScript libraries -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
// jQuery codes
$(document).ready(function(){
    // show sign up / registration form
    $(document).on('click', '#sign_up', function(){

        var html = `
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
            <form id='sign_up_form'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" required />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname" required />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" required />
                </div>

                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Sign Up</button>
            </form>
            `;

        clearResponse();
        $('#content').html(html);
    });

    // trigger when registration form is submitted
$(document).on('submit', '#sign_up_form', function(){

 // get form data
 var sign_up_form=$(this);
 var form_data=JSON.stringify(sign_up_form.serializeObject());


 // submit form data to api
 $.ajax({
     url: "api/create_user.php",
     type : "POST",
     contentType : 'application/json',
     data : form_data,
     success : function(result) {
         // if response is a success, tell the user it was a successful sign up & empty the input boxes
         $('#response').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>Successful sign up. Please login.</div>");
         sign_up_form.find('input').val('');
     },
     error: function(xhr, resp, text){
         // on error, tell the user sign up failed
         $('#response').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Unable to sign up. Please contact admin.</div>");

     }
 });

 return false;
});

    // show login form
$(document).on('click', '#login', function(){
    showLoginPage();
});

// trigger when login form is submitted
$(document).on('submit', '#login_form', function(){

 // get form data
 var login_form=$(this);
 var form_data=JSON.stringify(login_form.serializeObject());

 // submit form data to api
$.ajax({
    url: "api/login.php",
    type : "POST",
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : form_data,
    success : function(result){

        // store jwt to cookie
        setCookie("jwt", result.jwt, 1);

        // show home page & tell the user it was a successful login
        showHomePage();
        $('#response').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>Successful login.</div>");

    },
    error: function(xhr, resp, text){
    // on error, tell the user login has failed & empty the input boxes
    $('#response').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Login failed. Email or password is incorrect.</div>");
    login_form.find('input').val('');
}
});

 return false;
});

// trigger to show home page will be here

 // remove any prompt messages
function clearResponse(){
    $('#response').html('');
}

// show login page
function showLoginPage(){

 // remove jwt
 setCookie("jwt", "", 1);

 // login page html
 var html = `
     <h2>Login</h2>
     <form id='login_form'>
         <div class='form-group'>
             <label for='email'>Email address</label>
             <input type='email' class='form-control' id='email' name='email' placeholder='Enter email'>
         </div>

         <div class='form-group'>
             <label for='password'>Password</label>
             <input type='password' class='form-control' id='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'>
         </div>

         <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Login</button>
     </form>
     `;

 $('#content').html(html);
 clearResponse();
 showLoggedOutMenu();
}

// function to set cookie
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

// if the user is logged out
function showLoggedOutMenu(){
    // show login and sign up from navbar & hide logout button
    $("#login, #sign_up").show();
    $("#logout").hide();
}



// function to make form values to json format
$.fn.serializeObject = function(){

 var o = {};
 var a = this.serializeArray();
 $.each(a, function() {
     if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
         if (!o[this.name].push) {
             o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
         }
         o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
     } else {
         o[this.name] = this.value || '';
     }
 });
 return o;
};
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

After the JQuery ajax request it's should be display my custom success message: "Successful sign up. Please login" but instead it's always displays the error mesage: "Unable to sign up. Please contact admin." The JQuery POST request is successful because it saves the user's data in the database but on the webpage it's only displays the error message.

Comment: Did you inspect the error callback arguments for more details?

Comment: Can you check in your network panel the response code from the create user page?

Comment: *"The JQuery POST request is successful because it saves the user's data in the database"* - Your assumptions are invalid.  jQuery doesn't care about your database, it's only examining the HTTP response from the server.  In your browser's debugging tools, what is that response?

Comment: The response code from the create user page is 200 and I added dataType: "json", cache: "false", to the ajax call but still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the actual content type of response? What are the error arguments telling you? They are there for a reason

Comment: @VilmosSzabó: Is there anything on the browser's development console?

Comment: @BlackNetworkBit that's not accurate at all

Comment: I console logged xhr, resp and text and I got back this:
```javascript
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} "parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
    at l (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Well there you go...response is invalid json. Good lesson that should have checked there first.

Comment: I forgot to delete some code in create_user.php after I tested things. Now it's works as intended. Thank you!